# Jest throw an error "Class Extends value undefined" in angular during extension

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, ts-jest

I'm trying to migrate from jasmine to jest in angular project (v.13). I already applied all changes like:

1. Installed packages
2. Added jest config
3. Replaced needed parts of code (like Jasmine.SpyOn...)

Unfortunately, couple of components extends other components and because of that I receive such error:
`TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not constructor or null`

There's my component which I'm testing:

Base.component.ts

```
@Compponent({ 
   templateUrl: './template.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['/template.component.scss'],
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
   // Logic of that class //
}
```

And there's my child component:

```
import { BaseComponent } from '../components/BaseComponent';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-child',
   templateUrl: './child.component.html',
   styleUrls: [],
})
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {

    constructor(){ super(); }
}
```

My Test `child.component.spec.ts`

```
describe('Child Component', () => {
   let component: ChildComponent;
   let fixuture: ComponentFixture<ChildComponent>;

   beforeEach(async () => {
      await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [CommonsModule],
      }):
   });

   beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChildComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
   });

   it('should be created', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
})
```

My jest.config:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    testMatch: ['*.spec.ts'],
    rootDir: './',
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
        }
    }
}
```

My tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
    compilerOptions: {
        module: 'CommonJS',
        paths: {},
        ourDir: '/out-tsc/spec',
        types: ['jest', 'node'],
    }
}
```

Do you know how can I fix that issue? Will be really grateful! In Jasmine everything works fine... Just after changing jasmine to jest - it throws an error...